# Angular: Custom pipe event handling

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

This was asked in an interview.

Requirement is to create a custom pipe that would return a shortened text suffixed by a 'Read more' link for a text if it has more than a certain number of characters, lets say 10 characters.

If clicked on the 'Read more' link, the entire original text should be displayed suffixed by a 'Read less' link.
If clicked on the 'Read less' link, again the shortened text should be displayed suffixed by a 'Read more' link.
Thus, 'Read more' and 'Read less' links and short and original text should toggle on click of the links.

This entire functionality is to be implemented by a pipe only. Is event handling possible in a pipe? How we can handle events for the clicks on the links in the pipe?

Comment: No. A pipe is not the right tool for this job. A component is.

Comment: It's possible. But quite tricky! Helpful link: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/blob/master/src/pipes/string/shorten.ts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718823/angular2-add-read-more-link-to-custom-pipe

Comment: I don't know. That is quite too much logic for a pipe. Since it was an interview, maybe they wanted you  to challenge and wanted to see if you can find arguments against.

Comment: I think the ideal approach for this would be combination of a pipe for mutating the text and event handling in component for deciding whether to shorten or expand the text, by maintaining a flag for it. This flag can be passed as a parameter to the pipe to shorten or expand the text accordingly. But I think this is not scalable. If there are multiple such pipes in the same template then there can be side-effect of one pipe to the other while mutating the text.

Comment: There is a good article about pipes applications https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/11/08/5-usage-ideas-for-angular-pipes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the interviewer doesn't know the actual use of a pipe. Basically a `pipe` `shouldn't` handle like `these` `kinds` `of` `complex` `operations`. A pipe should handle some basic operations like

- Changing date time to locale
- Trim the string
- sorting the numbers based upon conditions etc.,

The best choice would be using a `Shared Component`. He can use this to communicate events between the components.